# Animação CSS não funciona no Mozilla

Tags: css, animação, firefox, cross-browser

Galera, estou com um probleminha em uma animação CSS.

Fiz ela funcionar normalmente no Chrome e até no IE, mas no Firefox ela da uma bugada. Já tentei colocar o prefixo `-moz-` em algumas propriedades, mas nada de funcionar.

Não sei se está correta a forma que eu fiz essa animação, mas aceito sugestões também. Valeu!

```css
.anima {
  will-change: transform;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 436px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-animation-name: effect; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 14s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: effect;
  animation-duration: 14s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/fazer-26fdbd895c.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; 

}


  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  @-webkit-keyframes effect {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    5%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/fazer-26fdbd895c.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    10%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    15%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/evoluir-fb7c0c3ecb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    25%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/evoluir-fb7c0c3ecb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    30%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    35%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/crescer-a364c2e9fb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    45%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/crescer-a364c2e9fb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    55%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acontecer-dedf63a20d.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat;transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    65%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acontecer-dedf63a20d.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    70%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    75%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acreditar-55f9efcefd.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    85%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acreditar-55f9efcefd.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    90%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    100%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/fazer-26fdbd895c.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
  }

  /* Standard syntax */
  @keyframes effect {
   0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    5%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/fazer-26fdbd895c.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    10%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    15%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/evoluir-fb7c0c3ecb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    25%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/evoluir-fb7c0c3ecb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    30%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    35%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/crescer-a364c2e9fb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    45%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/crescer-a364c2e9fb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    55%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acontecer-dedf63a20d.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat;transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    65%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acontecer-dedf63a20d.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    70%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    75%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acreditar-55f9efcefd.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    85%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acreditar-55f9efcefd.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
    90%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg);}
    100%  {background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/fazer-26fdbd895c.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat; transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); margin: 0 auto!important;}
  }
```

```html
<div class="anima"></div>
```

Disponibilizei o código no [CodePen](http://codepen.io/GiioohBernini/pen/BzdAwj) para quem preferir.

Comment: O que exatamente não está funcionando? Porque aparentemente aqui no meu mozilla estás a funcionar!

Comment: @IgorMello Igor, são 5 imagens diferentes, no meu mozilla ele repete a mesma até o final da animação

Comment: Ah ok, testei aqui no chrome e realmente o efeito é outro!

Comment: Acompanhando tenho o mesmo problema

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O seu problema é um bug do Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1036761 - O problema é que o Firefox não consegue animar a propriedade CSS `background` adequadamente.

Assim sendo, vamos bolar um workaround, que consiste em manter 5 `<div>`s diferentes, cada uma para uma figura, todas no mesmo local (por meio do `position: absolute;`) e combinar animações de forma a mostrar e animar uma delas enquanto as outras quatro permanecem ocultas. Para mostrar ou ocultar, eu uso `opacity: 1.0` ou `opacity: 0.0`.

Além disso, eu notei uns pequenos probleminhas no seu código original:

- No final do seu CSS, a imagem `fazer` deveria estar no 95% e não no 100% (isso fazia com que a duração/velocidade da animação dela ficasse um pouco irregular em comparação com as demais). Entretanto, [é importante frisar que os frames do 0% e do 100% não podem ser removidos porque eles que definem quais são as propriedades que serão animadas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#When_properties_are_left_out_of_some_keyframes).
- O `margin: 0 auto!important;` não precisaria ser repetido em vários *frames* da animação, bastaria colocá-lo uma vez no CSS da classe.
- No seu CSS original, a transição das imagens ocorria nos períodos entre 10%-15%, 30%-35%, 50%-55%, 70%-75% e 90%-95%. Nestes períodos, quando a imagem é vista de cabeça para baixo (em um ângulo baixo, entre 90 e 100 graus), na volta da animação, a imagem esmaece de uma para a outra. Na minha versão abaixo, uma imagem só começa a aparecer quando a anterior desaparecer (e por causa disso as percentagens que adotei diferem um pouco das suas), qualquer coisa é só ajustar as percentagens.

Assim sendo, aqui vai o código:

```css
.anima-box, .anima-box div {
  margin: 0 auto!important;
  max-width: 436px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.anima-box div {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 14s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-duration: 14s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.anima-fazer {
  -webkit-animation-name: effect-fazer; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: effect-fazer;
  background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/fazer-26fdbd895c.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.anima-evoluir {
  -webkit-animation-name: effect-evoluir; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: effect-evoluir;
  background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/evoluir-fb7c0c3ecb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.anima-crescer {
  -webkit-animation-name: effect-crescer; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: effect-crescer;
  background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/crescer-a364c2e9fb.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.anima-acontecer {
  -webkit-animation-name: effect-acontecer; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: effect-acontecer;
  background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acontecer-dedf63a20d.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.anima-acreditar {
  -webkit-animation-name: effect-acreditar; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: effect-acreditar;
  background: url("http://miceone.com.br/imagens/acreditar-55f9efcefd.svg") 0% 0% / contain no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes effect-fazer {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
    5%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   10%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   90%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   95%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
}

@keyframes effect-fazer {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
    5%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   10%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   90%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   95%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes effect-evoluir {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   10%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   15%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   25%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   30%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
}

@keyframes effect-evoluir {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   10%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   15%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   25%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   30%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes effect-crescer {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   30%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   35%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   45%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
}

@keyframes effect-crescer {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   30%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   35%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   45%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes effect-acontecer {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   55%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   65%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   70%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
}

@keyframes effect-acontecer {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   50%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   55%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   65%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   70%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes effect-acreditar {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   70%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   75%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   85%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   90%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
}

@keyframes effect-acreditar {
    0%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   70%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
   75%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   85%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 1.0;}
   90%  {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 100deg); opacity: 0.0;}
  100%  {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg); opacity: 0.0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="anima-box">
    <div class="anima-fazer"></div>
    <div class="anima-evoluir"></div>
    <div class="anima-crescer"></div>
    <div class="anima-acontecer"></div>
    <div class="anima-acreditar"></div>
</div>
```